# Can't seem to make a simple date comparison work to trigger a function

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to trigger a function when Date Value in a cell matches today's date, but it's not working. I'm not sure if it has something to do with date format.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
function refreshPage() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('1');
var date = sheet.getRange('R2')
var visit = date.getValue();
var today = setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
  
if(visit == today)
} //run the function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function refreshPage() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('1');
  const visit = new Date(sheet.getRange('R2').getValue()).valueOf();
  const dt = new Date();
  const today = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf()
  if (visit >= today) {
    //run the func
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper it worked. Thank you very much. Especially, I think you've given me a good understanding on how I can use dates as parameters next time.